# Fetch collection only one time

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i've a userlist made by a fetch from parse.com and rendered by view.Once people click on item list i've insert in url the objectid. In router i've made a function "home" that make fetch from collection and call view to render.The function "userdetails" catch objectid previous insert by view in url and use it to make a get from collection. The problem is:how can i pass the collection to this function userdetails?I don't want make another fetch.

```
        home: function() {
       var self=this;
           console.log("inrouterhome");               
           var utenti = new Usercollection();
      utenti.fetch({
      success: function(object) {

    var page=new Homelistuser({model:object}); 
    self.changePage(page);

     },
     error: function(amici, error) {
// The collection could not be retrieved.
    }
    }); 


    },


 userDetails: function (objectId) {

     HERE I WANNA USE OBJECTID TO MAKE A GET FROM COLLECTION FETCHED IN HOME
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is probably a scoping issue. Try this

```
var Models = {};
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
home: function() {
       var self=this;
           console.log("inrouterhome");               
           Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
           Models.utenti.fetch({
           success: function(object) {

              var page=new Homelistuser({model:object}); 
              self.changePage(page);

           },
              error: function(amici, error) {


                 // The collection could not be retrieved.

            }
     });
  },
  userDetails: function (objectId) {

    //Models.utenti should exist as long as home came first,
    // may want to write a condition that check to see if it exists and if not do fetch.
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @abritez mentioned this is probably a scoping problem i.e. the userDetails method doesn't have access to the instantiated collection. @abritez's solution resolves this but if the user refreshes the page or accesses the route directly the collection will not be loaded.

If the collection is used between both routes consider fetching it at run time and using a listener for when it's ready:

```
var Models = {};
Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
Models.utenti.fetch();
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  home: function() {
    var utentiLoaded = function(object) {
      var page = new Homelistuser({model:object}); 
      this.changePage(page);
    }

    this.listenTo(Models.utenti, 'reset', utentiLoaded);
    this.listenTo(Models.utenti, 'error', function(amici, error) {
      // The collection could not be retrieved.
    });

    if (Models.utenti.any()) {
      utentiLoaded(Models.utenti);
    }
  },

  userDetails: function(objectId) {
    var utentiLoaded = function(object) {
    }

    this.listenTo(Models.utenti, 'reset', utentiLoaded);
    this.listenTo(Models.utenti, 'error', function(amici, error) {
      // The collection could not be retrieved.
    });

    if (Models.utenti.any()) {
      utentiLoaded(Models.utenti);
    }
  }
});
```